# Keyboard Application - Best way to have multiple buttons add letter to textinput? Use event handlers?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, keyboard

I'm working on an application and I am building a "Keyboard" component for it.  There are 30 keys on the keyboard and it doesnt seem to make practical sense to create an event handler for each button.  When the button is clicked, its label should be sent out to a function which adds it to a textinput field.

Should I just create a "click=SomeFunction(Button.label)" for each button or is there a better/faster/less processor intensive way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a much easier way.  you can extend the button component and create a default click even that bubbles up.  You then can have the parent component listening for the event.  Here is a quick example:

myButton.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Button xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    click="clickKeyHandler( event );">

    <mx:Metadata>

        [Event(name="keyboardClickEvent", type="com.KeyboardEvent")]
    </mx:Metadata>

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import com.KeyboardEvent;

            protected function clickKeyHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void{


                dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent( this.label ) );
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Button>
```

com.KeyboardEvent:

```
package com
{
    import flash.events.Event;

public class KeyboardEvent extends Event
{

    public static const KEYBOARD_CLICK_EVENT:String = "keyboardClickEvent";

    private var _value:String;

    public function get value():String{

        return _value;

    }
    public function KeyboardEvent( value:String = "" )
    {

        super( KEYBOARD_CLICK_EVENT, true );

        _value = value;
    }


    override public function clone() : Event {
        return new KeyboardEvent( _value );
    }

    }

}
```

usage in app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="absolute" creationComplete="initApp();" xmlns:local="*">


    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import com.KeyboardEvent;

            private function initApp():void{


                this.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEYBOARD_CLICK_EVENT, keyboardHandler);

            }


            private function keyboardHandler( event:KeyboardEvent ):void{

                trace( event.value );
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <local:myButton label="1" />
    <local:myButton label="2" />
    <local:myButton label="3" />
    <local:myButton label="4" />
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Is the line "return new CompactReportEvent( _value );"
Supposed to say"return new keyboardEvent ( _value );" instead?

Comment: opps yea.  sorry I copied a pasted and missed that 1

Comment: I went through and fixed the example.

Comment: When I try to compile it, I get an error in the "this.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEYBOARD_CLICK_EVENT, keyboardHandler);" line.  The error reads "Access of possibly undefined property KEYBOARD_CLICK_EVENT through a reference with static type Class.

Any ideas?  Thanks for the help so far, I feel like I'm *almost* there.

Comment: I got it to work, I just substituted the line with the error:
 "this.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEYBOARD_CLICK_EVENT, keyboardHandler);" with:
this.addEventListener("keyboardClickEvent", keyboardHandler);
And replaced all references to that constant with the actual string "keyboardClickEvent"

Comment: its should work with the constants you just need to make sure the class is imported correctly.  Next time I will test the example in Flex before posting it..ha